# App Script shows variable as not used, but it is?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

The Google Apps Script editor is showing the x variable as grayed out, as though it is not used. Why?

```
function test2() {
  var x = false;
  x = true;
};
```

Obviously, I have code between the two lines but even in this simplest case it indicates that x is not used. Functionally it works, but I don't understand.

Comment: `x` is not used in the sense that its value is _set_, but never _gotten_.

Comment: I see that "return x;" and "!x;" will both cause the declaration to show as black, not gray. In these cases the value is gotten. Correct?

Comment: That is correct.